# OOP with type-checking in Lua

Tags: oop, lua, typechecking

I'm trying to implement classes with inheritance in Lua. Additionally, when creating new objects, there needs to be some kind of "type-checking".

One particular requirement is to use a specific syntax for creating a class (example):

```
Class({Volkswagen, Vehicle, model=String, speed=Number, driving=Boolean})
```

Please note that the parameters are passed as a list with variable length. So I need to have a function that gets an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
function Class (arguments)
    name = arguments[1]
    superclass = arguments[2]
    ...
end
```

The first two arguments are the name of the class and the name of the class it is inherited from.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I have absolutely no idea how to handle the key-value pairs of the attributes, for example...

```
print(arguments.model)
print(type(arguments.model))
```

...are both nil. Any ideas how i can get the type of the attributes (String, Boolean, Number)?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
{Volkswagen, Vehicle, model=String, speed=Number, driving=Boolean}
```

Does not mean what you think it means. It's the values.

When you do `{Volkswagen}`, what you're doing is telling Lua to grab the value currently stored in the global table under the string name `"Volkswagen"`. I'll assume that there's some value stored there.

Your problem is that `{model=String}` is putting the value currently stored in the global table under the string name `"String"` into the table. Odds are good that there *is no* global variable named `"String"`. Which means you put `nil` in the table.

Unless LuaJava defines them, the "attributes" (String, Boolean, Number) do not exist. They're just empty values. You can't pass an empty value. You can pass a *string*, but that's different.

You didn't explain very well what exactly this `Class` function of yours should be doing, so I can't give you a hint on how to do what it is you're trying to do better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a generic Lua class system, here's my implementation:
https://gist.github.com/1722329

It doesn't support type checking, but that should be easily implemented with a "TypedClass" class to act as a base for all strictly-typed classes.

Answer (score 0):

For handling the key value pairs you may need to transfer the referenced table to a local table using the built in table function:

```
function Class(params)
local arguments={}

function transfer(k, v)
  arguments[k]=v
end

--transfer referenced table to local table
table.foreach (params, transfer)

print(arguments[1])
print(arguments[2])
print(arguments.model)
print(arguments.speed)
print(arguments.driving)
```

end

Class({"Volkswagen","Vehicle", model="" , speed=0 , driving=false} )